# A complete graph on 5 vertices with coloured edges

Tags: graphics, color, graphs

I was unable to create a complete graph on 5 vertices with edges coloured red and blue in Latex. The picture of such graph is below. I would be very grateful for help!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). 

Otherwise, more specifically about your question: You should clarify your question with the packages you want to use ( `tikz`, `pstrick`, ...) and give a minimal example showing your previous attempts.

Comment: It is possible to create your drawing yourself with a tool https://tikzit.github.io/

Answer (score 10):

- Use polar coordinates `(angle:distance)`. For a pentagon, the angles differ by 360/5 = 72 degrees. Since one node is supposed to be at angle 90 (north), the angles are computed from there as 18, 90, 162, 234, and 306 degrees.
- Lookup the `\foreach` loop as well as the `\draw` and `\node` commands in the [TikZ manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\size{1}% distance of nodes from center
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick,red]  (18:\size) \foreach \a in {90,162,234,306} { -- (\a:\size) } -- cycle;
  \draw[thick,blue] (18:\size) \foreach \a in {162,306,90,234} { -- (\a:\size) } -- cycle;
  \foreach \a in {18,90,162,234,306} { \node[black,fill=black,circle,inner sep=2pt] at (\a:\size){}; }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Very easy using MetaPost:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[latex,shellescape]{gmp}
\begin{document}
\begin{mpost}[name=nice]
numeric u; u := 3cm;
for i = 1 upto 5:
    for j = 1 upto i:
        if i <> j:
            draw (u*dir (72i+18)) -- (u*dir(72j+18)) withcolor
            if (abs(i-j) = 1) or (abs(i-j) = 4):
                red
            else:
                blue
            fi
            withpen currentpen scaled 4;
        fi
    endfor
endfor
for i = 1 upto 5: drawdot (u*dir (72i+18)) withpen currentpen scaled 20; endfor
\end{mpost}%
\usempost{nice}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very good and I approved with the stamp. :-)

Answer (score 7):

An alternative (for exercise), with using of the `regular polygon` shape and double loop:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3.141592]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, fill=black, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0pt}
                    ]
\node (n)   [regular polygon, 
             regular polygon sides=5, minimum size=22mm,
             draw=red, thick]  {};
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,5} 
{     
    \foreach \j [evaluate=\j as \k using int(\i+\j)] in {2,3}
    {
    \ifnum\k<6
    \draw[thick,blue]   (n.corner \i) -- (n.corner \k);
    \fi
    }
\node [dot] at (n.corner \i) {};
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Graphs can be produced with the `graphs` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph [nodes={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill},radius=1.75cm, 
    clockwise, empty nodes,n=5] { 
    subgraph I_n [clique,edge=blue]; 
    subgraph C_n [edge={red,semithick}]; ,
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]